# Erro ao criar thread dentro de um Handler

Tags: java, thread

Preciso dar um delay de 5 segundos em uma das partes da minha aplicação:

```
final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Encadeia trabalho serializado
        jobChain.append(new Job() {
            public void doJob(final OnChainItemListener itemListener) {
                // Obtém metadados do Artigo
                onlineArticle.get(idArticle, new HttpJsonObjectListener() {
                    public void onRequestCompleted(JSONObject object, Integer httpStatus, CharSequence msg) {
                        offlineArticle.save(object, new HttpJsonObjectListener() {
                            public void onRequestCompleted(JSONObject object, Integer httpStatus, CharSequence msg) {
                                Log.v(this.getClass().getName(), "Artigo salvo!");
                            }
                        }, null);

                        itemListener.onRequestCompleted(object, httpStatus, msg);
                    }
                }, defFail);
            }
        });

    }
};
new Handler().postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
```

Tentei implementar, mas acontece que tudo isso fica dentro de um handler e ele me dá o seguinte erro:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that
>   has not called Looper.prepare()

Li a respeito, que teria que executar na thread principal, mas não estou conseguindo fazer.

Comment: Pode postar o código da sua thread principal? É onde a outra thread foi chamada, a main thread.

Comment: Acredito que esteja chamando métodos que lidam com interface dentro de uma thread que não tem permissão para tal. Dê uma olhada nessa resposta aqui do SO [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3875204/5165061)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi fazendo o seguinte:

```
private void createHandler() {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
      public void run() {
           Looper.prepare();

           final Handler handler = new Handler();
           handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   // Ação a ser atrasada
                    handler.removeCallbacks(this);
                    Looper.myLooper().quit();
               }
            }, 2000);

            Looper.loop();
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
```